# How do I zip/unzip on the unix command line?

Tags: command-line, zip

How can I create and extract zip archives from the command line?

Comment: @joachim, you should ask the question in a question and provide an answer in an answer. There's no problem with answering your own questions but not as part of the question itself, since that breaks down the whole community-votes-on-the-best-answer advantage of SO. In addition, this is probably better suited for superuser since it's not programming related.

Comment: Where will you document how to get online and check SO if you forget your login?

Comment: @rlb.usa: I work in a lot of different places on a lot of different servers. Using SA for a note like this helps other people too, as I see it.

Comment: For quick ziping file, I usually use `gzip *`

Comment: `python -m zipfile --help` if you don't want to install zip/unzip and have python.

Answer (score 816):

Typically one uses `tar` to create an uncompressed archive and either `gzip` or `bzip2` to compress that archive. The corresponding `gunzip` and `bunzip2` commands can be used to uncompress said archive, or you can just use flags on the `tar` command to perform the uncompression.

If you are referring specifically to the [Zip file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29), you can simply use the `zip` and `unzip` commands.

To compress:

```
zip squash.zip file1 file2 file3
```

or to zip a directory

```
zip -r squash.zip dir1
```

To uncompress:

```
unzip squash.zip
```

this unzips it in your current working directory.

Comment: I personally only ever use the `zip -r9 archive.zip files...` syntax (-r=recursive -9=max compression).

Comment: Just as a side note: `zip` can create many different flavors of .ZIP archives, as well as use many different compressors. On the other hand, there are a number of other compression tools named similarly: 7-Zip, gzip, bzip2, rzip, etc. which are not interchangeable.

Comment: In case you don't want the parent directory to be included: `cd dir1; zip -r ../squash.zip *`

Comment: I'm confused, I did this and get a long list of inflations and extractions but when I check the directory it is empty, save for the original zip file? Where is it all going?

Comment: Omg, in your current working directory! I thought that meant the directory it is in, not the directory you are `cd`ed in. OOPS!

Comment: For the record, use `unzip -d myfolder squash.zip` to extract into a separate new directory (`myfolder`) instead of putting all the files directly into the current directory, which can be annoying if the zip file contains many files and directories in its top level. This mimics how most UI unzip tools work.

Answer (score 79):

There are a truly *vast* number of different ways to compress and uncompress under UNIX derivatives so I'm going to assume you meant "zip" in the generic sense rather than a *specific* file format.

You can zip files up (in compressed format) with the GNU `tar` program:

```
tar -zcvf myfile.tgz .
```

which will do the current directory. Replace `.` with other file names if you want something else.

To unzip that file, use:

```
tar -zxvf myfile.tgz
```

That's assuming of course that you have a `tar` capable of doing the compression as well as combining of files into one.

If not, you can just use `tar cvf` followed by `gzip` (again, if available) for compression and `gunzip` followed by `tar xvf`.

---

For specific handling of ZIP format files, I would recommend downloading `7zip` and using that - it recognises a *huge* variety of file formats, including the ZIP one.

Comment: Or use `tar jcvf file.tar.bz2...` to compress in bzip2 format or `tar Jcvf file.tar.xz ...` for xz compression.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because the question is about how to deal with zip archives not tar files.

Comment: @Starfish, that's certainly within your rights, thanks for at least explaining why, so many people don't take the time to do that :-) I took "zip" in the more generic sense (compression) rather than a specific format, so I'll make that more clear.

Comment: Be aware that tar archives may not work correctly when moving between different platforms, mac to linux or vice versa. Zip is much safer, as it works correctly on all systems.

Comment: I suppose technically this is gzip, so that's fine. I guess. Pretty obviously not what the question asked for though.

Answer (score 41):

If you don't have zip and unzip packages installed and you have java, you can use `jar` to unzip:

```
jar -xf file.zip
```

Comment: Not my server, no unzip, zip, 7z, nothing... And this worked. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great tip.

Comment: We need `jdk` in advance to execute this command.

Answer (score 29):

Well, when it comes to distributing files for a variety of operating systems, I'd recommend [7-zip](http://7-zip.org).

Usually in the package `p7zip`, you'll get the `7z` and `7za` command, with which you can create your own 7z archives.

`7za` can also decompress standard ([pkzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKZIP)) zip archives (and create them as well with the `-tzip` switch).

Compressing:

```
7za a archive.7z file1 file2 directory/
```

Decompressing:

```
7za x archive.7z
```

It can also create self-extracting archives with the `-sfx` switch:

```
7za a -sfx archive.exe files1 file2 dir
```

I recommend this method in case Windows users can't open 7z archives (in case you want to advice a tool for that: [PeaZip](http://www.peazip.org/)).

If you want to use the same compression algorithm with your tarballs, use the `-J` switch with `tar`:

```
tar cJf archive.tar.xz file1 file2 dir
```

[`xz`](https://tukaani.org/xz/) is a UNIX tool, that uses LZMA2 for compression, but works the way `gz`, `bz2`, etc works. It even works as a filter.

7z doesn't create archives with full filesystem information on UNIX, so you'd need to use `tar` before using 7z (but since 7z stores other information about the `tar` file, I'd recommend using `xz`, as it is designed for it):

```
tar cf - file1 file2 dir | 7za z -si archive.tar.7z
```

Comment: I should perhaps append this answer with `atool`, it's a nice little tool that makes using many different compressors more comfortable. Bind that to `a` and creating an archive becomes `a arc.7z folder/` or extracting a simple `a arc.7z`

Answer (score 28):

```
unzip <filename>
```

and

```
zip -r archive.zip <filename> [filename]
```

You'll need to make sure these commands are installed via your package manager. It's no harder than using anything else on the command line. It's certainly simpler than creating archives with tar.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but this is the best answer. Doesn't talk about 7z or tar, its concise and straight to the point

Answer (score 5):

BSD Tar can also do this

```
bsdtar -a -c -f sunday.zip sunday.jpg
```

Or:

```
bsdtar -x -f sunday.zip
```

Comment: BSD `tar` has the benefit of supporting quite a few additional compression formats compared to GNU `tar` and other `tar`s. The greatest benefit is, perhaps, that it does so _while using a `tar`-like syntax_. You can surely use `7z`, `unrar`, `unzip`, etc from the commandline, but they use a _different_ syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The most standard answer is [`pax`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_(Unix)), which is recommended over [`cpio`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) and [`tar`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format)).

Unlike `cpio` and POSIX `tar`, but like GNU `tar`, `pax` is able to both archive files and compress the archive. This behavior is different from [`zip`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)), which compresses each file before putting it in the archive.

Comment: Does `pax` support zip archives?

Comment: Nope and it doesn't support `pax` archives either!

Answer (score 2):

This covers only extraction.

For that, I've started to use [`dtrx`](https://brettcsmith.org/2007/dtrx/).

The whole point of it is to remove complexity. So you just pass in any archive to it and it figures out what needs to be done with it. Zip, tar, gz... Use is always the same — `dtrx archive.zip`. It asks a few questions and you're done.

`dtrx` is available in most repositories, so you can `apt`|`yum` install it.

Answer (score 1):

I often find myself trying to zip the modified files in my work directory -- either to copy all the modified files to another sandbox work directory or to preserve them for a short while because I want to undo some of the changes.

In that case, I copy the list of modified files to a temporary file and use `zip` with the option `-@`.

Let's say I modified the files Foo.h, Bar.cc, and TestBar.cc.

Let's say I create a file called modified-files.txt whose contents are:

```
Foo.h
Bar.cc
TestBar.cc
```

I execute the following command to zip those files:

```
cat modified-files.txt | zip modified-files.zip -@
```