# How can I zip by specifying directory?

Tags: filenames, zip

I want to zip a directory not everything in the path. 
I know the command `zip -r squash.zip dir1`
From the post: [How do I zip/unzip on the unix command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/how-do-i-zip-unzip-on-the-unix-command-line)

But when I run the command using the absolute path:

`zip -r squash.zip /path/to/dir1`

Zip creates folders to the path also and I get in the zip folder `/path/to/dir1`. What I want is only `dir1\sub\dirs`

Answer (score 2):

it's best to navigate to that specific directory parent and run the zip from there and then store the zip somewhere else.
e.g.
`cd /path/to`

`zip -r /home/user/dir1.zip dir1/`

Comment: The problem I have is I am running a script and I am using absolute paths. So navigating to a directory is not possible.

Comment: you probably want to have something like this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin)